# My script with for loops in list comprehensions is slower that normal for loop

Tags: python, performance, for-loop, list-comprehension, astropy

I just wanted to speed up my script which contains many loops, so I tried with list comprehensions. So my initial approach was:

```
 gt_cat=open(gt)
 next(gt_cat)
 gf_cat=open(gf_celestial_out)
 gt_reader=csv.reader(gt_cat)
 gf_reader=csv.reader(gf_cat)
 gf_coords_list=[]

 for index_row, gf_line in enumerate(gf_reader):
     gf_coords=SkyCoord(ra=[float(gf_line[0])]*u.degree,
                                dec=[float(gf_line[1])]*u.degree)
     gf_coords_list.append(gf_coords)

 gt_coords_list=[]
 for index_column, gt_line in enumerate(gt_reader):
      gt_coords=SkyCoord(ra=[float(gt_line[3])]*u.degree,
                         dec=[float(gt_line[4])]*u.degree)
      gt_coords_list.append(gt_coords)


    for row in range(dist_matrix.shape[0]):
        for column in range(dist_matrix.shape[1]):
            seperation=gf_coords_list[row].separation(gt_coords_list[column])
            dist_matrix[row][column]=seperation.value
```

This style took 95 sec to finish the job. Of course there is more code except from that, but those are the "big" loops.

After that I used:

```
gf_ra, gf_dec = zip(*[(float(line[0]), float(line[1])) for _, line in enumerate(gf_reader)])
gt_ra, gt_dec=zip(*[(float(line[3]), float(line[4])) for _, line in enumerate(gt_reader)])

gf_coords_list = [SkyCoord(ra=gf_ra * u.degree, dec=gf_dec * u.degree) for gf_ra, gf_dec in
                          zip(gf_ra, gf_dec)]

gt_coords_list=[SkyCoord(ra=gt_ra * u.degree, dec=gt_dec * u.degree) for gt_ra, gt_dec in
                        zip(gt_ra, gt_dec)]
for row in range(dist_matrix.shape[0]):
    for column in range(dist_matrix.shape[1]):

        seperation=gf_coords_list[row].separation(gt_coords_list[column])
        dist_matrix[row][column]=seperation.value
```

This code, together with the rest of the script takes 103 sec.

Moreover, I tried

```
gf_coords_list=[SkyCoord(ra=[float(gf_line[0])]*u.degree, dec=[float(gf_line[1])]*u.degree) for
                        index_row, gf_line in enumerate(gt_reader)]
```

and

```
gt_coords_list=[SkyCoord(ra=[float(gt_line[0])]*u.degree, dec=[float(gt_line[1])]*u.degree) for
                            index_row, gt_line in enumerate(gt_reader)]
```

instead of the for loops but again it was slower..

Comment: List comprehensions were made so you don't need a bulky loop for a simple task. Sometimes, such as in this case, it may be slower to use a list comp. I would suggest you keep to a normal loop, but you could check out `map` and `filter` as they go down to the C level to run their loops.

Comment: Don't use `enumerate()` if you don't need the indexes. Just use `for line in gf_reader`.

Comment: It's not likely that the looping mechanism is the bottleneck here, it's probably what you're doing in the loops, like the calls to `SkyCoord()`. Use a profiler to find out where the time is being spent.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. So SkyCoord is super fast, and by not using enumerate doesn't help. yes i thought about map but I have some difficulties in implementing it.

Comment: There is only negligible differences in execution speed for a for loop and an equivalent list comprehension. `map` is generally slower, as it requires a function call on each iteration

Comment: Putting your exact question aside for a moment, were you aware that Astropy already has a very fast built-in CSV reader for astronomical tables, which among other things will handle conversion of floating point numbers, and return your data in a table object? I would not be surprised if it gives you orders of magnitude improvement over trying to do this yourself http://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/io/ascii/fast_ascii_io.html

Comment: Get that working, and the next improvement you can make is rather than creating many `SkyCoord` objects, for each coordinate, you can instantiate a *single* `SkyCoord` with ra and dec arrays.